# Python: skimage.transform.hough_circle_peaks() min_xdistance and min_ydistance errors

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I am trying to use the skimage.transform image modules to find and assess the fluorescence of circles on a slide. So far the modules are working very well indeed. However I have one small issue I cannot seem to fix.

When using skimage.transform.hough_circle_peaks() I found the same pots were being identified multiple times, instead of all spots across the slide. 
Whole slide image:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2LSj.png)

Screen shot of where circles are being stacked on the same spots:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4V7s.png)

I tried to remedy this by using the following:

min_xdistance : int, optional
Minimum distance separating centers in the x dimension.

min_ydistance : int, optional
Minimum distance separating centers in the y dimension.

I set these both to 1000 pixels, which given that each circle has a radius of ~33 pixels, should mean no circle will be identified twice, and no circles adjacent should be selected either. However I now see this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfc84.jpg)

You can see that while fewer circles are found, two are still places on top of each other.  Does anyone have any thoughts or experience with this?

Comment: Related issue https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/2728

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @soupault!

Comment: Script_badger given @soupault's comment, it looks like there is a known bug in skimage. In the meantime I suggest you implement your own filtering: given an output from hough_circle_peaks, rank peaks in decreasing order, and as you traverse this list, if you find a peak that doesn't overlap with previous peaks, add to "accepted" list. If it overlaps with peak in "accepted", discard.

Comment: @soupault Thanks very much for the link and the pointer, very helpful! I will implement this.